# Iframe source to be a dynamic URL

Tags: html, post, iframe, submit, form-submit

Not using iFrames very often so I could really do with your help here...

I have a form on a webpage which opens an external online booking engine with availability depending on the dates selected in the form.

I'd like to open the external booking page in an iframe named "mainframe" on a new page, book.html.

The start and end code for the form is:

Code:

```
  <form name="roseform" method="post" action="http://www.hotelexec.co.uk/external.asp"></form>
  <input type="text" class="dimmed" placeholder="Brasil" id="keywords" name="keywords" />
  <a href="#" class="btn" onclick="submit()">Search</a>
```

How would I set the target to "mainframe" at the book.html page so the results from the form would be displayed there? I understand I need to make Iframe source to be a dynamic URL.

Thanks,

Blazer

Answer (score 2):

Just add **target** attribute.

```
<form name="roseform" target="mainframe" method="post" action="http://www.hotelexec.co.uk/external.asp"></form>
```

**UPDATE**

As I understood you need this steps:

For start change **.html** to **.php**

Change action of form in `itmjobs.ro/lidl/page1.php` to point page2.html

```
<form name="roseform" method="post" action="http://itmjobs.ro/lidl/page2.php"></form>
```

In page2.php add iframe with address `http://itmjobs.ro/search-results-jobs/`

```
<iframe src="http://itmjobs.ro/search-results-jobs/?<?php echo http_build_query($_POST)?>"></iframe>
```

Now you will see data from `http://itmjobs.ro/search-results-jobs/` in your iframe.

Comment: Will this load book.html with results after submit data on page1 ?

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong. Could you please explain more. You have form and button, after clicking on button you need to go http://www.hotelexec.co.uk/external.asp and same time load book.html in frame?

Comment: http://hotelexec.co.uk/external.asp is the form link within iframe. We enter text in page1, push search- that will trigger page2 to load with results in iframe within.

Comment: Incredible.. almost one week lost, I opened 4 posts around this subject and I finally got the answer from you in 5 minutes. Thank you so much ! Now tell me if I can change files back to html because the whole site is html and only the iframe page content is made in Smarty

Comment: You need to change **server configuration** to understand html files like php.

Comment: Great,  thanks again ! I would push useful answer 100 times but I can't :)

Comment: Actually it didn't work with html extension. Will do any harm if I let those files with php extension ?

Comment: No, only difference is what apache will parse data between `<? ?>`, in you case only part with frame address.

Comment: If you have time maybe you can help me to auto resize based on search results http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547009/iframe-auto-size-based-on-content-that-changes-size-based-on-search-results