# iframe auto size based on content that changes size based on search results

Tags: javascript, iframe, resize, autosize

I have one page that contains search page iframe . If you try to search for a text it will rarely fit the page.

I don't know what code to use to auto resize iframe based on content changes.

Right now I use this code in iframe :

```
 <body onload="parent.alertsize(document.body.scrollHeight);">
```

And this javascript in parent page :

```
 <script>
function alertsize(pixels){
 pixels+=32;
 document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.height=pixels+"px";
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myHeight = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    if(myHeight != document.body.scrollHeight){
        myHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
        parent.alertsize(myHeight);
    }
},500);
</script>
```

Comment: You are incredible. Thank you. Do you have an email ?

Comment: Yes, but as I know it forbidden to write it in comments.

Comment: Almost... First name yes, last name no ;)

Comment: It's ok, you need to include them to make this script works. I got your message on plan.am, but email was empty.

Comment: Your email is a mystery. I have sent several contact forms to both plan.am and biznet.am . Also on your facebook  :)